# Is it possible to rooting bluestacks?

Tags: adb

Actually I am new to `Bluestacks emulator`. I am try and testing it but please someone help me how to this `Emulator`. Thanks in advance. If possible please share some link of video or attach some images.

Comment: https://bstweaker.tk/bluestacks-all-download for direct download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to root Bluestacks, but you need tweaker named as `bstweaker`. For download visit to https://bstweaker.tk/ and also check this youtube video [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWLfsv_4ZS4&ab_channel=RoHTeChZ) you will get all the things very easily.